# Can't sculpt on some parts of the mesh

Tags: sculpting

I am using blender 3.0 and it happens to me that I am unable to modify some parts of my mesh.

- There are no masks applied as shown in the beginning of the video.
- I recalculated normals as suggested in another answer but it didn't work

Please can someone explain what am I doing wrong and what would make it to work correctly.
Thank you.

[image]

EDIT:

**FILE URL:**
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/1939915cd5ae24db9c5243bd337559b420220227093402/d029dc3c016b15f1dc7d151d1d446d2220220227093430/bee0bf

Comment: Hello please share your object: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: it doesn't allow to upload large file sizes. Had to be large because of dense mesh, allowing me to sculpt.

Comment: use another platform like wetransfer, send the file to yourself then share the link it will give you

Comment: Added the url in my question, thank you :)

Comment: weird because it seems to work fine for me: https://zupimages.net/up/22/08/l8gh.gif

Comment: Hey it works after a certain point.. if you sculpt enough on the top and bottom and makes those areas match the edges length, it starts to work. Please rotate the model and try to sculpt where I haven't. Thanks again for taking out time for this .

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, I hope someone will understand